# Поиск слово в тестовом файле

Tags: c++

Есть текстовый файл(text.txt) в нём большой текст. Нужно найти определённое слово в тексте. Пример:

Нужно найти слово "тест"
аываывафа фыва ыва*тест*авыаываывавы

PS. Слова в тексте может и не быть.

Comment: А что вы пробовали? Можно, к примеру, читать построчно и искать при помощи библиотечных функций.

Comment: @VladD Я ещё нечего не пробовал, не знаю даже с чего начать. Есть идея сделать так. Продвигаться по 1 символу. Если символ текста == 1 первому символу слово то начинаем сравнение.

Comment: @Илья Чижанов: Попробуйте так:

* читайте файл построчно (вот [пример](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), как)
* в каждой строке ищите подстроку при помощи простого [`string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)